# PHP Water mark script with using GD library function imagejpeg Error

Tags: php, gd

I have been using the Watermark script used [here](http://www.htmlguard.com/articles/dynamic-image-watermarks-with-php/) for creating water mark on image on my site. From last month the images that are being process by this script are not showing. I get the following error in firebug console.

```
Image corrupt or truncated: http://www.mysite.com/data/10.jpg
```

Looking at the error log for server i have this line there

```
PHP Warning:  imagejpeg(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/mysite/public_html/data/watermark.php on line 80
```

Please suggest where the issue is. I checked server info which shows GD library is enabled.

PS: This is working correctly on my local server. I have PHP Version 5.3.1 on local and 5.4.19 Online.

Answer (score 5):

Figured this Out. It was an issue with PHP version.

In PHP **5.3**

```
imagejpeg($image, '', 100);
```

in **5.4**

```
imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);
```

Hope this would help someone.