# Moved CakePHP 1.3.8 Install Image Issue

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cakephp

I'm trying to move an old CakePHP 1.3.8 installation between servers and having issues with certain images not displaying.

Old Server:
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Apache 2.4.7
MySQL 5.5
PHP 5.5.9
PHP (GD, MYSQL)

New Server:
Centos 7.5.1804
Apache 2.4.6
MySQL 5.4
PHP 5.4
PHP (GD, MYSQL)

I've verified that DocumentRoot is pointing to the Cake /app/webroot directory as well having an AllowOverride All directive in the sites config.  Also verified the (3) .htaccess files, mod_rewrite, etc.

Debug is set to '2' in core.php but the only error logged is regarding an image function:

```
imagejpeg() [<a href='http://php.net/function.imagejpeg'>function.imagejpeg</a>]: Filename cannot be empty
```

Examples of what's happening on each project page-

[Working Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOEOf.png)

[Non-Working Site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8HJg.png)

Everything else, including database access is working.  I know next to nothing about cakephp but going through the various files, it looks to me like this function is being called from the file 'detail.ctp' under the views/projects directory:

```
<?php echo $html->image('/App/ContentImageView/'.$image3.'/250/400',array('title'=>'Project Image', 'id'=>'MainImg', 'alt'=>'Project I    mage', 'class'=>'border2')); ?>
```

And the function from app_controller.php

```
function ContentImageView($img_path, $w = '75', $h = '75'){
    Configure::write('debug', 2);
    debug($img_path, $showHTML = true, $showFrom = true);
if (empty($img_path)) return;
    $image = str_replace('@@', '/', $img_path);
    if (empty($image)) return;
    $this->autoLayout = false;
    $this->autoRender = false;
    if(empty($image)) return;
    //image resize parameters
    $FileConfig = array();
    $FileConfig['source_image'] = WWW_ROOT . '/'. $image;
    $FileConfig['dynamic_output'] = true;
    $FileConfig['maintain_ratio'] = true;
    $FileConfig['width'] = $w;
    $FileConfig['height'] = $h;
    ini_set('memory_limit', -1)
    $this->ImageLib->clear();
    $this->ImageLib->set($FileConfig);
    $this->ImageLib->resize()
}
```

All the code works perfectly on the old server so I'm thinking is some kind of configuration path issue but I just can't put my finger on it.

Thanks all.

Comment: Have you compared the src attribute of the images between the working and non-working pages? Check to see if the path of the image is correct, and that the image is stored on the server in the specified folder.

Comment: What is `$this->ImageLib` (`debug(get_class($this->ImageLib))`)? Does it perhaps make use of some PHP module like `gd` which is installed on the old server but not the new one?

Comment: Also, this code looks susceptible to a potential directory traversal attack.

Comment: Paths + directory paths check out.  I added a couple of debug statement s to the view page and the paths are displayed correctly.  The site does use the PHP gd module.  On the new server is PHP-gd-5.4.  PHP --info yields GD Support => enabled and GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible).  As for the potential attack, I will look into it.  Thanks

Comment: The warning should come with a file name and a line number (please always post the complete message). Look at where the error actually is actually triggered, ie the place where `imagejpeg()` is being invoked. Also check existing questions regarding the same warning, like **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19888246/php-water-mark-script-with-using-gd-library-function-imagejpeg-error**

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  The line number does reference a error in a function called 'image_display_gd' in image_lib.php.  Changing the double single quotes to a 'NULL' however doesn't fix the issue.  Strange too the the working server is running a  slightly newer version of PHP and works.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a Centos 6.9 VM with PHP 5.3.3 and the issue is not present.  Must be a change in PHP as ndm pointed out.  Rather than trying to figure out where the code must be updated, we are moving forward on Centos 6.9 as this site will be retired soon anyway.

Thanks again to everyone who responded.